# Unsupported Mac Mojave display Issue

Tags: macos-mojave

The Mac built-in display is unresponsive to closed lid state and causes external display not to respond to resolution adjustment behavior on an unsupported Mac running macOS Mojave.

**New Tag Request**
unsupported-mac &
mac-display

Answer (score -1):

Easy fix/workaround for this is to download a program that I fianlly found. Super easy. Here it is. https://github.com/Eun/DisableMonitor. Download and run. Click the display icon in menu bar and navigate to appropriate device and select disable. This will cause your external monitor to take true full power of your display environment.